# Prestashop 1.7 Overriding default presta module source files

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Is it possible to override module source files? for example:
modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Ps_FacetedsearchFiltersConverter.php

There is no problem to override module file but all the src files are being loaded from original path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to create file into override/modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Ps_FacetedsearchFiltersConverter.php and delete class_index.php into var/cache ?